# How to start my search from a particular range of cells say(A8) from the userform in the respective excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Right now I am able to populate the excelsheet data into userform from second row only i.e. A2 whereas my Excel sheet starts from A8.

I have given the range as A8 to start from but it is not displaying any data in the userform when i search with a Serial number.

Below is my Code for search and update. Can anyone suggest me where I should insert the range for search and update button.

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    If Me.TextBox1.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "SL No Can Not be Blank!!!", vbExclamation, "SL No"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    SLNo = Me.TextBox1.Value
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A8").Select   'I added this as a new line to start from this range

    Dim rowselect As Double
    rowselect = Me.TextBox1.Value
    rowselect = rowselect + 1
    Rows(rowselect).Select
    Cells(rowselect, 2) = Me.TextBox2.Value
    Cells(rowselect, 3) = Me.TextBox3.Value
End Sub


Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
    Do
        DoEvents
        row_number = row_number + 1
        item_in_review = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A8" & row_number)  'Range A is replaced with A8

        If item_in_review = TextBox1.Text Then
            TextBox2.Text = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & row_number)
            TextBox3.Text = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & row_number)
        End If
    Loop Until item_in_review = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: I need to start my search from A8 cell because from A1 to A7 are empty cells.

Comment: I tried moving as you suggested and then I am getting error in this line "TextBox2.Text = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & row_number)" and the value of row number is empty.

Comment: I tried and this time no error when I changed it to A7 but data from Excel sheet is not populating on the userform.

Comment: I'd use `item_in_review = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A7").Offset(row_number)`. Furthermore I'd add an `Exit Do` right before `End If`

Comment: Can you please edit in my Code.

Comment: you can using the [edit] functionality. @DisplayName has given you the code.

Comment: @santoshpaladhi, why that? You just have to copy and paste my suggestion in your code...

Comment: `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A8" & row_number)` equal to `A81` cell, so you loop from A81 down. Try `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row_number)`. Just set `row_number = 8` before loop and move `row_number = row_number + 1` after the endif as @QHarr suggested.

Comment: @Sphinx perfect it worked thanks alot to everyone. May I know even for updating the data in the same row of my search shall I keep rowselect = 8.

Comment: I am not able update in A8 row it is going to A2 row.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're up to. In  `cmdSearch_Click()` you search for `TextBox1.Text` on your sheet and if found corresponding values are copied to userform. In `cmdAdd_Click()` you probably want to copy values from userform back to your sheet, right? Could you describe what's going on step by step on your userform, also some example of data could be usefull (eg some screenshot)

Comment: @Sphinx I solved the problem. My target was first to search using a Serial number say "1" in the userform and edit the data and update the same from the userform to the Excel sheet of the Serial number "1" row.